# Access violation error in vulkan.Corruption of integer variable

Tags: visual-c++, vulkan

I am learning vulkan and have come accross an error "Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF98C0D16B5 (vulkan-1.dll) in ProjectV.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000. occured"in an unusual step.
Usually at this step I am not supposesd to encounter any problems.In the second line of the code snippet Ive counted the number of QueueFamilies using the countIndex variable.I used this function before in a different method while creating Logical Device but have not received any error then but now I do so.I am receiving the title error at line 3 of the snippet, at the cout line.

Although I am not supposed to get error at such simple step.I even tried static_cast while printing because I thought the data type created a problem, but that too did not work.

```
uint32_t countIndex=0, queue_fam_index=0; VkBool32 check = VK_FALSE;
vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties(dev, &countIndex,nullptr); 
std::cout << static_cast<int>(countIndex) << "\n";
std::vector<VkQueueFamilyProperties>  que_fam(countIndex);
vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties(
 dev,&countIndex,que_fam.data());
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with line 3. Seems like your environment is messed up in some basic way. Can you confirm that a simple "hello world" program works? It would also help if you showed evidence of attempting to debug this yourself, e.g. stepping into the code in a debugger, or showing a stack trace of the crash.

Comment: The error is generic, you are possibly feeding Vulkan `nullptr` somewhere. Make sure the error is not in a different thread. You did not mention the state of Validation Layers.

Comment: Most of the time 0xC0000005 is a segfault, which means you are doing some out of bounds indexing (either with an array, nullptr, or other pointer uninitialized access).  You can figure out precisely where such an error occurs when using the visual studio debugger (which I assume you are using).